# Inherit Tags from AEM Parent to Child Page

Tags: aem

Is there a way to make certain tags to be inherited from a parent page to a child page in AEM?

Say Parent page has tags A,B,C,D and I need to make B be inherited to all child pages created for this parent page.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! For people to be able to help you, please include the code you have tested. It's much easier for people to help if they can see the code you have tested. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for tips.

Comment: Can you describe the use case in some more detail? Are you building a custom component that needs to display or otherwise use those tags? Are you looking for a way for this kind of inheritance to work with some built-in functionality such as search or OOTB components?